# OTB ImageClassifier -The following layers were not correctly generated

Tags: otb-applications

After running the OTB ImageClassifier, I get always the error message:
`The following layers were not correctly generated.`

What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you still encounter this issue if you try with paths that have no space chars?

Answer (score 1):

The QGIS pluggin for OTB doesn't work correctly when there are spaces in file paths. I see you use as input "...\Neuer Ordner...". Try renaming this directory "Neuer_Ordner".

There is an error message in the logs you shared:
"Could not read file C:/Users/Dominik"
If there is a space in your user directory, you need to change that too...

EDIT: You could also try to add quotes "" around file paths in QGIS.